# How can I set yup validation based on two conditions? I am using TypeScript with Next.js and Formik

Tags: next.js, conditional-statements, formik, yup

I want to set this **endedAt field** to be required if the value of this **current** property is equal to **true** and the value of this **endedAt property** is **null**.

Here is what I have tried:

```
validationSchema: Yup.object({
      title: Yup.string()
        .trim()
        .min(1, t('min-length-x', { x: 1 }))
        .max(128, t('max-length-x', { x: 128 }))
        .required(t('required')),
      organizationName: Yup.string()
        .trim()
        .min(1, t('min-length-x', { x: 1 }))
        .max(128, t('max-length-x', { x: 128 }))
        .required(t('required')),
      description: Yup.string()
        .trim()
        .min(0, t('min-length-x', { x: 0 }))
        .max(1024, t('max-length-x', { x: 1024 })),
      endedAt: Yup.date()
        .when(['current', 'endedAt'], {
          is: (!current, endedAt) => {
            return (!current && endedAt === null)
          },
          then: Yup.date().required(t('required')),
        })
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your endedAt like this. So that it can take the value of current, lazy is just used to avoid circular dependency error.

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  title: Yup.string()
    .trim()
    .min(1, t("min-length-x", { x: 1 }))
    .max(128, t("max-length-x", { x: 128 }))
    .required(t("required")),
  organizationName: Yup.string()
    .trim()
    .min(1, t("min-length-x", { x: 1 }))
    .max(128, t("max-length-x", { x: 128 }))
    .required(t("required")),
  description: Yup.string()
    .trim()
    .min(0, t("min-length-x", { x: 0 }))
    .max(1024, t("max-length-x", { x: 1024 })),
  current: Yup.boolean(),
  endedAt: Yup.lazy((value) =>
    value && value.current
      ? Yup.date().required(t("required"))
      : Yup.date().nullable().default(null)
  )
});

 
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: "",
    organizationName: "",
    description: "",
    current: false,
    endedAt: null
});
```

Comment: remember to pass empty sting for invalid date error <input
  type="date"
  id="endedAt"
  name="endedAt"
  value={formData.endedAt ?? ''}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>